# No location Coordinates without internet with SignificantLocationMonitoring

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, gps, core-location

I am trying to record location coordinates in background in swift iOS.
When app enters background I use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and when it enters foreground I use `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` and `startUpdatingLocation()`.
I have instantiated location manager properly in `finishLaunching`.
Everything seems fine when iPhone is connected to internet but for some reason when no internet is available it seems as I do not get any location coordinates and no call to `didFailWithError`.

While in foreground it at least gives error : `Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"`

But for background it does not even give error while I travelled 30KM.

For purpose of debugging I use local notification to notify me in case of callback to didFailWithError and didUpdateLocations.

With active internet connection it mostly works fine even if application is killed or in background but when I try the same without wifi or cellular data I seem to get not response at all. How to handle GPS setup and monitor users location as I want it all sorted by itself in background. Is there any explanation to this behavior. I need to have offline behavior if internet is not there.

Thanks

Comment: Are you disabling the internet connection by putting the device in airplane mode?

Comment: Are you in a country that uses GSM?

Comment: Yes shallowThought.

Comment: @Andrea Yes for debugging I am switching airplane mode off/on to trick iPhone into believing that cellular network changed. Another thing I noticed is Application is not relaunched from dead as it should in Significant location until I switch on wifi.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation:

> **Determining the Availability of Region Monitoring**
>
> Before attempting to monitor any regions, your app should check
>   whether region monitoring is supported on the current device. Here are
>   some reasons why region monitoring might not be available:
>
> The device doesn’t have the necessary hardware to support region
>   monitoring. 
>   The user denied the app the authorization to use region
>   monitoring.
>  The user disabled location services in the Settings app.
>   The user disabled Background App Refresh in the Settings app, either
>   for the device or for your app.
>  **The device is in Airplane mode and
>   can’t power up the necessary hardware**.

The problem you are experiencing is consistent with this extract from "[Region Monitoring and Ibeacon](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1)" documentation section.
Try to change your test by disabling WiFi and disabling cellular data.

Comment: Thanks @andrea but I am not working with region monitoring. For debugging I am switching off/on airplane mode for few seconds which gives iPhone impression that cell tower is changed and it should give callback to location manager delegates, but there are no callbacks when device is not connected to internet or wifi. I think desired behaviour of significantMonitoring is it should wake up GPS when Cell tower change and if failed to get location it should call didFailWitherror, which is not happening. However with cellular data it gives callbacks to delegate properly in background. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think that Region monitoring is a close parent of significant location changes. I'm also skeptical about GPS working, this kind of feature are used to avoid battery drain. :)

Comment: Thanks.. you are right, they are great in saving battery. Is there any explanation that SignificantLocation does not give any callbacks to delegate without internet or cellular as there will be time in my App when its not connected to internet and if it fails to get location from GPS it should at least call didFailwithError which is not the case.